# How can I connect to SQL Server CE using web.config

Tags: asp.net, database, web-config, sql-server-ce-4

I would like to know how can I connect to a SQL Server Compact Edition database from my web application?

Usually I insert the connection string in the code. How can I connect to the database which is situated in `App_Data` in the `web.config` file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/

Answer (score 0):

In your `web.config` have a `connectionString` like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=|YourDirectory|\DBName.sdf"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Further reading **[here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-compact/)** if required.